# READ_CALL_LOG permission issue on Google Play Store release

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, permissions, google-play

I'm setting my app as default dialer still my app is being rejected by app store for using READ_CALL_LOG

We literally tried everything to fix it, even restricted it's usage to very low even after setting app as default dialer, still that issue persists.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, were you able to fix it?